# Parsing html with html agility pack

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

I want to collect all  tags in from this div but do not know how to do this in the best way with xpath method

```
<div class="biz_info">
    <h3><a href="/profil/78122/s%C3%B8rby-rehab/">Sørby Rehab</a></h3>
    <table class="string_14">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td>Postadr.:</td> 
               <td class="tab_space">Rognerudveien 8 B, 0681 Oslo</td> 
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Telefon:</td> 
                <td class="tab_space">928 70 700</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Nettside:</td> 
                <td class="tab_space"><a href="http://www.sorby-rehab.no" target="_blank">www.sorby-rehab.no</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Today my code looks like this (but very bad):

```
 HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load(new StringReader(result));
HtmlNode root = doc.DocumentNode;

List<string> anchorTags = new List<string>();

foreach (HtmlNode link in root.SelectNodes("//@class=biz_info"))
{
    string att = link.OuterHtml;
    anchorTags.Add(att);
}
```

Is someone who is professional in xpath that can help me?

Answer (score 0):

```
HtmlDocument html = new HtmlDocument();
html.Load(new StringReader(result));
var anchorTags = html.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='biz_info']//a")
                     .Select(a => a.OuterHtml)
                     .ToList();
```

That will give you list of anchor tags html. If you need just urls:

```
urls = html.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='biz_info']//a[@href!='']")
           .Select(a => a.Attributes["href"].Value)
           .ToList();
```

Comment: how do I do if I want to loop this out? because the "biz-info" is about 20 pieces? :)

Comment: @Mrmaxen use loop, e.g. with *foreach*: `foreach(string a in anchorTags) { ... }`

Comment: @lazyberzosky, Now, I have tried to build for your model but it works not work. What I want the goal is to get all biz_info and gene rara them to xml file. would be nice if shit could help me a bit. here's the code : http://pastebin.com/sS8UVts8

Comment: @Mrmaxen sorry, I don't understand how saving data to xml is related to parsing html

Comment: My problem right now is that I have to get all divs so I later then you can save it down to one exampel xml-docs or excel.

Comment: The ones I do not want to, I want to get all the information from div biz info and i can debugged so I can see what the code does :)

Comment: @Mrmaxen set breakpoint right after `anchorTags` assignment and you'll see all tags. I don't get what you are trying to achieve. From your sample code I see that you are trying to get `anchorTags` from `div`. Correct?