# Get the value of all td tags using xpath and html agilty

Tags: c#, xpath, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

How can I get information out of all td tags in Classen = "string_14" so that I can store it away clean without html code in.

I have thought about this:

```
enter code here
<table class="string_14">
                <tbody><tr>
                    <td>Postadr.:</td> 
                    <td class="tab_space">Stenslivegen 67, 2817 Gjøvik</td> 
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Telefon:</td> 
                    <td class="tab_space">611 80 710</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>Mobil:</td> 
                    <td class="tab_space">957 92 455</td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
                </table>
```

And my code to get it looking like this today, I want help with is to write xpath to name =? how should I write to get a single td.

```
        HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.Load(new StringReader(result));
        HtmlNode root = doc.DocumentNode;


        List<string> list = new List<string>();
        foreach (HtmlNode div in root.SelectNodes("//div[@class='biz_list']"))
        {
            string name = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//d[@class='string_14']/@tr");
            list.Add(name);
            string att = div.OuterHtml;
            list.Add(att);
        }
```

What I want out of this is I'm going to scrape a page and then the LATE stage I'll save this down to the xml file.

Comment: What are you getting as a result when you currently run what you have listed above..?

Comment: Looks like you created new account. I recognize this code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15501810/parsing-html-with-html-agility-pack I'll flag this account for moderator attention

Comment: I want to have, for example

string postcode = Stone Serfs 67, 2817 Gjøvik
String Phone = 611 80 710

Comment: lazyberezovsky, help me instead of lowering myself

Comment: I can help you, but you should delete this account and ask question from your first account (btw you can be banned for multi accounts)

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is this:

```
HtmlNodeCollection collection = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[@class='string_14']//td[@class='tab_space']");
```

You can consult [XPath Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/) for more on this.

Comment: They say : Cannot implicitly convert type 'HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeCollection' to 'string'


do you have any idea of the problem

Comment: Oh I didn't even check your initial code for that. Answer updated.