# Regular Expression for achor tag

Tags: asp.net, regex

Want to get href link from anchor tag. I am using

```
regex = @"<a[^>]*?href\s*=3D\s*[""']?    ([^'"" >]+?)[ '""][^>]*?>".
```

I can get successfully if href in single line but it fails on the following

```
Text = <a target=3D"_blank" hr=
ef=3D"http://abc.com/blog/check-your-cars-health-before-going-on-lo=
ng-trip/">
```

File which is reading is eml file and not a html file
Kindly suggest correct regex for above

Comment: try it w/o the first \s as I cannot spot a whitespace after href. Alternatively try \s* which means "zero or more" whitespaces

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be really trying to parse HTML with regular expressions, [this](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html) is essentially why. You could take a look at a robust HTML processesing library such as the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15501810/parsing-html-with-html-agility-pack) previous SO post might have something which does something along the lines of what you are doing.

Comment: You were a few seconds ahead of me (although I don't really believe it's an answer - more a comment).  This sort of thing is very hard with RegEx.  I'd also suggest using HTML Agility Pack http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Comment: @Liath: Yes HTML shouldn't be processed with regex. Why do you think that this should be a comment? I did propose an alternative method to what the OP is asking and also included information on how can this be done.

Comment: It was simply because the question was about RegExes rather than how can I do this... but that's just down to the phrasing of the question.  I agree 100% that this is the correct approach.

Comment: I think your first clue would be in the OP `not a html file Kindly suggest correct regex for above`

Answer (score 0):

## Description

This regex will:

- find the href attribute value inside the anchor tag
- avoid some difficult edge cases

`<a\b(?=\s)(?=(?:[^>=]|='[^']*'|="[^"]*"|=[^'"][^\s>]*)*?\shr=.*?ef=3D['"]([^"]*)['"]?)(?:[^>=]|='[^']*'|="[^"]*"|=[^'"\s]*)*"\s?\/?>.*?<\/a>`

[image]

## Example

**Sample Text**

Note the difficutl edge case in onmouseover

`<a onmouseover=' href="NotTheHrefYoureLookingFor" ; funRotator(href) ; ' target=3D"_blank" href="http://abc.com/blog/check-your-cars-health-before-going-on-lo=
ng-trip/">link text
</a>`

**Capture Groups**

```
[0] => <a onmouseover=' href=" hr=
ef=3D NotTheHrefYoureLookingFor" ; funRotator(href) ; ' target=3D"_blank" hr=
ef=3D"http://abc.com/blog/check-your-cars-health-before-going-on-lo=
ng-trip/">link text
</a>
[1] => http://abc.com/blog/check-your-cars-health-before-going-on-lo=
ng-trip/
```